# PySpark - Read multiple sas7bdat files as Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sas, data-migration, python-regex

I am trying to create a dataframe with multiple sas7bdat files matching a pattern lying under a single directory with the same schema.
`spark.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load("/users/shobhana/sas_files/filename_*.sas7bdat")` and getting an error as `No such file "/users/shobhana/sas_files/filename_*.sas7bdat" exists`.

In actual there are multiple files : filename_2201.sas7bdat,filename_2202.sas7bdat,filename_2203.sas7bdat etc..

Neither `spark.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load("/users/shobhana/sas_files/*.sas7bdat")` is working. Please suggest.

Comment: Try `spark.read.format("com.github.saurfang.sas.spark").load("/users/shobhana/sas_files", pathGlobFilter="*.sas7bdat")` ([docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-generic-options.html#path-global-filter)).

Comment: pathGlobFilter didn’t work . It’s not taking any patterns